# conda install (or any other command) not working for Win64

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I seem to be having a problem using conda on Windows x64. I installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 but every conda command fails with the same error. I've had no luck with google. Has anyone encountered this?

"Error: Could not find URL: https://binstar.org/auto/win-64/" 
The site in question 404's and I dont seem to know how to change conda from going to that website.

EDIT: Reinstalling (and rebooting) didn't work.

Comment: I'd suggest (also) asking this on the Anaconda mailing list: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/anaconda .

Comment: I got the accepted answer a day earlier at the mailing list, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `auto` channel from your `.condarc` file (probably in `C:\Users\Your Name\.condarc`).

Comment: Thank you, I actually just deleted the file and it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with anaconda 2.3.0

The bug for me was a bogus extra line in the `.condarc` file, with just `S` on a line by itself. Delete that bogus line and everything worked.

If you went in and edited the `.condarc` file, removing the `auto`, you may have fixed this without even realizing it.